# Disabling Media Request Protection isn't working

Tags: media-library

I just experienced (what I believe is) an issue on one of our sites in which disabling Media Request Protection in a Sitecore 8.0 site isn't working.

I set the `Media.RequestProtection.Enabled` setting to `false` and confirmed that the patch was applied correctly in the ShowConfig. However, any media on the site that doesn't have the MRP hash is not scaling properly (using `h` and `w` parameters), while any media with the MRP hash is. I feel like this shouldn't be the case when MRP is disabled.

I have tried disabling browser caching, requesting without and with the hash, clearing the sitecore cache, enabling MRP, disabling MRP, rinsing and repeating. Each time, the only media that scales is media with the MRP hash, whether or not I have MRP enabled.

Does anyone know if there is something else that I could be missing or if I am misunderstanding what disabling MRP actually does?

***Side-Note:*** I know that MRP is important and I have every intention of using it. Recently on one of our sites, MRP hashes were accidentally removed from several renderings. The change went unnoticed until it was deployed to production and the very media-intensive site started failing automated load-tests. I noticed the issue with disabling MRP when I attempted to temporarily disable MRP on production to prevent the site from going down/performance from plummeting for a few hours while we fixed and tested the issue before redeploying to production.

Comment: Possibly answered here? http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/image-not-being-resized-properly-sitecore-8-1-rev-160519

Comment: Unfortunately not, @MarkCassidy. I had a look at that one before posting. It's about how to properly apply the hash. We don't have any issues applying the hash. My question is about why scaling doesn't work when we intentionally don't add a hash and intentionally have MRP disabled. That question was the reason, however, why I included the side-note about recognizing the importance of MRP (hopefully saved someone a few keystrokes) ;)

Comment: Right ok :-)   Just looked similar, on an admittedly quick-scan ;-)

Comment: Did you add any custom imaging configs like cropping, etc... I had this issue in the past and it was because the image processing pipeline was breaking it. For me the hashing was working because of a combination of browser cache Sitecore cache in /App_Data folder.

Comment: Nope, @dnstommy, I just verified. Based on your comment, I took a pass at the `<getMediaStream>` pipeline but everything was default. I also checked the `<initialize>` pipeline and saw everything that I was expecting there, as well.

Comment: have you tried disabling the config? `Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config` - > `Sitecore.Media.RequestProtection.config.disabled`

Comment: I haven't because I was patching the setting and confirmed that the patch was being applied in the ShowConfig. I'll give it a shot though, just in case.